# Functions over a discrete set of points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Given a variety $V$ over a field $k$ cut out by the ideal $(I)$ the functions over $V$ are given by the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(I)$. As a toy example, take $y=x^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$ then we have a ring of functions $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y-x^2)\cong \mathbb{C}[x]$. This makes sense because $y=x^2$ is a curve so the functions along it are going to be the same functions that we would get on the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$. Now consider $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2-1)$ which is equivalent to the ring with elements of the form $\{a+bx:a,b\in\mathbb{C}\}$. These are functions over a two point set. I am struggling to understand what exactly it means for the functions over a two point set to be lines. My initial thought was that two points define a unique line but that does not explain how lines are the only functions over the two point set. My intuition tells me that functions over the two point set should be $\mathbb{C}^2$ because you can pick a value for one point and a value for the other one. Am I understanding functions on a variety incorrectly? How should I understand functions over the two point set?

Comment: I assume you mean $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2-1)$? Either way, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2-1)\cong\mathbb C^2$, the bijection given by evaluation at $x=\pm1$.

Comment: @KentaS definitely overthought it there, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite inaccurate to say that these are "lines." They're elements of the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 - 1)$. This quotient is $2$-dimensional and you can take $\{ 1, x \}$ to be a basis. $1$ is the function on the two-element set $\{ \pm 1 \}$ with constant value $1$, while $x$ is the function which takes value $\pm 1$ on $\pm 1$. It's easy to check that this is a basis. A more familiar basis might be the functions $e_{\pm 1}$ which take the value $1$ on $\pm 1$ and $0$ otherwise, which in terms of the functions $1$ and $x$ are given by $\frac{1 \pm x}{2}$.

As Kenta says in the comments, the isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}^2$ is given by

$$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 - 1) \ni f(x) \mapsto (f(1), f(-1)) \in \mathbb{C}^2.$$

Comment: Quick follow-up: how should I think about this when considering $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$? How are the functions over a double point different from those over two distinct points (if there is any difference)?

Comment: This is more complicated because we no longer have an easy interpretation in terms of functions. You can think of elements of that ring as recording the first two terms of the Taylor series expansion of a polynomial (or even a smooth function) at $x = 0$. Similarly $\mathbb{C}[x]/x^n$ records the first $n$ terms.